# change every nth element of a vector R

Tags: r

I have:

```
ls = 1:14
```

I change value of every element except the first, last, and every 4th element from counting from the end

I would like:

```
ls = c(1, 2, "", "", "", 6, "", "", "", 10, "", "", "", 14)
```

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: Side note - `ls` probably shouldn't be used for a variable name unless you have a great reason.  `ls` is a base R function and you are allowed to overwrite names like this but it makes code less clear so I suggest not using that unless you have good reason to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
ls[-c(1, seq(14, 1, -4))] = ""
```